# Converting JSONArray to POJO Using Jackson

Tags: arrays, jackson, pojo

I'm new to Jackson, recently I've tried to convert JSONArray to POJO. But POJO haven't got populated. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22993398/5423330) post's second comment, I have added @JsonProperty to getter and setter then it worked fine.

Here is my question, why its not populated by itself without @JsonProperty.

Note: this is how my JSONArray and POJO's setter looks like:

JSONArray:

```
{"emp":[{...},{...},{...}]}
```

POJO:

```
public void setEmp(ArrayList<Employee> emp)
{
    ...
}
```